# WebAudio setTargetAtTime: formula to convert-time constant to seconds

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I've found I like the sound of `setTargetAtTime()` applied to gain. So I'd like to do this:

```
 gainNode.gain.setTargetAtTime(0, audioContext.currentTime, timeConst) 
 oscillator.stop(audioContext.currentTime + timeConstToSeconds(timeConst));
```

So that the oscillator stops when the sound is functionally inaudible. 
What is an effective `timeConstToSeconds()` function for this?

And/or, what is an effective formula for the reverse operation? (input seconds, return time constant.)

Comment: Why note use a [`linearRampToValueAtTime`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioParam/linearRampToValueAtTime) instead of setTargetAtTime?

Comment: The fade sounds a bit different, and I like the setTarget sound. Also, it seems that different browsers perform differently in terms of tracking the automation parameter. (Still figuring that out though.)

Comment: If they are different between browsers, be sure to file bugs against the browser.  It can't get fixed if they don't know about it.

Answer (score 1):

The spec tells you exactly how `setTargetAtTime` works: https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#dom-audioparam-settargetattime

As a rough general rule, these kinds of exponential approaches are generally considered to have converged to the final value after 5 or 10 time constants, so

`function timeConstToSeconds(t) {
  return 10*t;
}`

Change `10` to some other appropriate value for what you consider to be close enough.